# (React js) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using **nested map function** in the code below. First map function is for showing cattle details from **state** and 2nd map function is for getting images name from **ImageName** state. **setstate** is successfully getting data from response. I saw some solutions on internet to set an **initial value** to states, but still getting the error.

**Component.jsx**

```
const ShowCattle = () => {

    const { lstate } = useContext(LoginContext);
    const [state, setstate] = useState([]);
    const [ImagePath, setImagePath] = useState({});
    const [ImageName, setImageName] = useState([]);


    const ShowData = async () => {

        await fetch('/show-cattles', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                lstate
            })
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            res.json().then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setstate(data);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    const ShowList = () => {

  
        const ImgArray = state.map((item) => {
            return item.image;
        })

        setImageName(ImgArray[0]);
        
        setImagePath('/upload/');

        return (
            state.map((cvalue, index) => {

                return (
                    <div key={index}>

                        {
                            ImageName.map((value, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={index} >
                                        <img src={ImagePath + index} alt="img" />
                                        <h6>Cattle Image Name : {value}</h6>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })

                        }

                        <h6>Cattle Name : {cvalue.cattle_name}</h6>
                        <h6>Cattle Type : {cvalue.cattle_type}</h6>
                        <h6>Cattle Age : {cvalue.cattle_age}</h6>
                        <h6>Cattle Description : {cvalue.cattle_des}</h6>
                        <h6>Cattle City : {cvalue.cattle_city}</h6>
                        <h6>Cattle Price : {cvalue.cattle_price}</h6>
                        <hr />
                    </div>

                )
            })
        )

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        ShowData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="my_body">
                        <h1>Show Cattle Page</h1>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <ShowList />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: One of the values you pass to `setstate` or `setImageName` must be undefined. We can't help you without seeing what you set your states to.

Comment: ok i am editing the code.

Comment: I added all the code check it now.

Comment: Is the error thrown by `state.map` or `ImageName.map`?

Comment: You were right. One value in ImageName state was undefined. Now code is running perfect. Thanks for helping.